# Virtual Host with Xampp redirecting to dashboard on windows

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I am sure I will regret this but I have done tons of research throughout stackoverflow and the almighty google.  I am just trying to setup a virtual host for my project and I followed a couple of tutorials for different methodologies but no matter what it either doesn't work at all or just redirects me to the xampp dashboard with the url `lavamap.dev/dashboard`.  Below I have included all the files I have been messing with, and yes I always restart Apache after changes.

**Versions:** 
Windows- 10 
Xampp - 3.2.2 
Apache- 2.4

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/lavamap"
    ServerName lavamap.dev
    ServerAlias www.lavamap.dev
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/lavamap">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   lavamap.dev
127.0.0.1   www.lavamap.dev
```

I also uncommented the following line from httpd.conf

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Thanks for even taking the time to read this and even more thanks so for any responses! I'll take clues, hints, ideas or a solution.

Comment: Restarting Apache fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real answer! As far as I could tell I just uninstalled and reinstalled and it worked fine.  The funny part is I did the same steps in my home environment and it only works in firefox and not chrome.  I may just be bad with apache but damn it feels a little unstable.  I wish I could post an answer that would help other more.

Comment: The `.htaccess` of `C:/xampp/htdocs` will affects its sub directory `C:/xampp/htdocs/lavamap` To be sure, checkout your new installation, either there is no `.htaccess` in the `C:/xampp/htdocs` or you have created another one the sub directory that override the other on the root directory.
**AS general hint** in such cases avoid craeting VH document root in sub directories of other hosts, then also useful to use another local loop IP other than `127.0.0.1` i.e `127.0.0.3`, `127.0.10.30` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. After googling for two days finally i got down to debug. The problem is with how google chrome is treating the url. It is redirecting all your url to https://lavamap.dev/dashboard and for this the port is by default 443. That's why it seems like httpd-vhosts.conf is not working properly. But here comes the other file in action i.e. httpd-ssl.conf. For any https protocoal the virtual host entries goes in to this file. so you have to make virtual host entry in httpd-ssl.conf. Hopefully it will solve your problem.